# How to ignore first entered character to be zero in a textbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, zero

Basically, I do not want the user to enter '0' (zero) as the first character in a textbox which represents data with type of integer?

I would like to bind an event handler to handle this with jQuery.

Any experience?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you wish to prevent the action during keyboard entry, or "fix" the text once it is presented (during validation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply replace it on the keyup like this:

```
$('#test').keyup(function() {
   if ($(this).val() === '0')
   {
      $(this).val('');
   }    
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't  `if($(this).val() == '0') $(this).val('');` be easier? :)

Comment: Yep, that makes it even easier.  Got caught up in the keyup event arguments.  I edited the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the value with the integer value if you want:

```
$(".IntegerInput").val(function(i, v) {
  return parseInt(v, 10);
});
```

This will parse the int and replace the value with it, removing any leading 0's.

[Romuald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286182/romuald-brunet) made a god catch, for your specific case you'll need the radix argument on `parseInt()`

Comment: Won't work as intended. For example `parseInt('0100')` returns 64.  

Just use `parseInt(v, 10)` and it will work fine

Comment: @Romuald - Good catch, didn't think think about it defaulting leading 0 to a different base, updated

Answer (score 0):

you can use somthing like  `$('textbox').val().substr(0,1) != 0`;
Though it would be better if we knew what you would like accomplish